# TransportError 'Permission Denied' in Google

Tags: python, google-maps, google-app-engine

I am setting up a project in Google App Engine using the Google Maps APIs through the Python Client Libraries for Google Maps Web Services

I tried the following example code:

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='MY API KEY HERE')
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')
```

and yes, I did put my actual API key there.  In fact, it all works just fine in an Anaconda iPython console, but in Google Apps Engine, I get:

> File "C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Apps\oncourse\main.py", line 31
>
> geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain
>   View, CA')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Apps\oncourse\lib\googlemaps\geocoding.py",
>   line 68, in geocode
>
> return client._get("/maps/api/geocode/json", params)["results"]
>
> File "C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Apps\oncourse\lib\googlemaps\client.py",
>   line 204, in _get
>
> raise googlemaps.exceptions.TransportError(e)
>
> TransportError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission
>   denied'))
>
> INFO     2015-11-22 20:14:23,002 module.py:794] default: "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 -

What does this error actually mean?

I imagine that I don't have all of the libraries set up correctly,

my app.yaml file contains

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

and I installed the googlemaps library in a lib folder in my app's root directory.  The `gmaps=Client(key)` instantiation works (I tested it by outputting gmaps.key), so I believe I have the google maps library properly set up.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Seems like the problem is with installed version of *requests*. I had installed google maps inside *libs* using

```
pip install -t lib googlemaps
```

This had installed *requests-2.6* inside *libs*.
I deleted the *requests* and *requests-2.6.0.dist-info* directories, manually from *libs* and then installed *requests-2.3* using

```
pip install -t lib requests==2.3
```

That solved the problem for me.
Hope it helps.